# cc1plus: error: unrecognized argument in option '-march=native'

Tags: gcc, cmake, arm, g++, cross-platform

I'm trying to cross compile [OpenPano](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/OpenPano) for linux arm using cmake. I'm getting an error:

> cc1plus: error: unrecognized argument in option '-march=native'

But then it says that this is a valid argument:

> cc1plus: note: valid arguments to '-march=' are: armv2 armv2a [...] native

I'm confused. If it's a valid argument then why is it unrecognized?

**gcc version:**

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 5.3.0

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ (GCC) 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

1. It is right - *native* means the architecture of the compiling machine which is not very applicable when you cross-compile :)
2. They just probably forgot to remove it from the displayed string.

I would rather do not rely on the usage displayed. Better check the documentation instead :)